# Regex check on list

Tags: regex, string, swi-prolog, is-empty

Why does `isempty()` not return multiple values, like `writeln()`, but just a single false:

```
:- use_module(library(regex)).
isempty(Str) :- Str =~ '^\s*$'.

?- maplist(writeln,['','  ','p','']).

  
p

true.

?- maplist(isempty,['','  ','p','']).
false.
```

Comment: `isempty(Str) :- Str =~ '^\\s*$'.`?